# Internet Explorer Transparency

Tags: css, internet-explorer, transparency, opacity

i am using the opacity of an object on a site to hide it unless hovered, and when hovered it reveals itself.

However for internet explorer this little css trick isnt working. Previously i did not include the

```
filter:alpha(opacity=0);
```

CSS tag. but now the CSS reads as follows:

```
#title-0, #title-1, #title-2, #title-3, #title-4, #title-5, #title-6, #title-7, #title-8 
{
-o-transition:all 0.2s linear;
-ms-transition:all 0.2s linear;
-moz-transition:all 0.2s linear;
-webkit-transition:all 0.2s linear;
transition:all 0.2s linear;
zoom:1;
filter:alpha(opacity=0);
opacity: 0.0;
}
```

When hovered

```
#portfolio-0:hover > #title-0, #portfolio-1:hover > #title-1, #portfolio-2:hover > #title-2, #portfolio-3:hover > #title-3, #portfolio-4:hover > #title-4, #portfolio-5:hover > #title-5, #portfolio-6:hover > #title-6, #portfolio-7:hover > #title-7, #portfolio-8:hover > #title-8         
{
opacity:1.0;
zoom:1;
filter:alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

Is there something major im missing?

All help appreciated, this works perfect in all major browsers as far as i've tested except IE

//// *** UPDATE *** ////

Okay so as per the fantastic answers so far this is what i've altered the "NOT-HOVERED" css to, this should HIDE the title unless the image is hovered.

```
#title-0, #title-1, #title-2, #title-3, #title-4, #title-5, #title-6, #title-7, #title-8
{
-o-transition:all 0.2s linear;
-ms-transition:all 0.2s linear;
-moz-transition:all 0.2s linear;
-webkit-transition:all 0.2s linear;
transition:all 0.2s linear;
zoom:1;
filter:alpha(opacity=0);
opacity: 0.1;
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
<!--[if IE]>
opacity: 0.01;
<![endif]-->
}
```

But the object im trying to hide is still shown :/

Comment: Is the version of IE you're using 10+

Comment: i am using 10+ yes the person who noted it to me wasn't so i just wondered if i have catered for all IE versions that i possibly can?

Comment: IE10 has a bug - try setting IE opacity value to *almost* 0 - a really low value like .01

Comment: thank you is there anyway to only target IE so i can set opacity:0.01 ? is that a valid value?

Comment: Hello, i've updated original post, with new css (still not hiding the element?)

Comment: It should be a valid value as long as you're not using MS specific toolkit options. As for condition checks, I see you've found that.  If it's still not hiding I'm out of answers. Best bet is a rigorous net search.

Answer (score 0):

What version of IE are you trying to cater for?

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-opacity/

This website should provide you with the answer, have a look at the line:

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
```

Obviously change the opacity value to be (Opacity=100) on hover

Also in your hover you have

```
filter:alpha(opacity=0);
```

it should be

```
filter:alpha(opacity=100);
```

Comment: Thank you, i did see this, but i wondered that DXImageTransform? does this mean it will only apply to images?

Comment: No it will apply it to everything it can.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help :) okay so- I added the first line of code this doesn't seemed to have made all the difference and corrected my "hovered" code with the filter. Still can't get this to work?

Comment: The -ms-filter is for older versions of IE. If you are using 10+ then I suggest you use the 0.01 value as fnostro said above.

Comment: Hello, i've updated original post, with new css (still not hiding the element?) really confused?

Comment: You cannot do if statements in your CSS, they have to be within the HTML, but IE10 ignores them. Have a look at this, it works in my IE10: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wbDHl/

Comment: that worked for me and when applying (the rule you set) to my css it still had no effect, is there something overriding it on my site i wonder? the link is here: http://megabooth.com/ if you could look i would be so thankful. The transparent background AND text ontop of the scrolling marquee is what im trying to hide. I wonder if it's ignoring the NOT-HOVERED css and opting to listen to the hover css?